# Resources on a smooth topos containing complex analytic/holomorphic geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, topos-theory, synthetic-differential

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186851/synthetic-vs-classical-differential-geometry) Urs Schreiber mentioned there are models in synthetic differential geometry of complex analytic geometry.

First of all: When Urs writes complex analytic geometry, does he mean complex manifolds/a category containing them, or something entirely different?

In any case, can someone provide resources on that?